# Is SharePoint 2019 last version of SharePoint?

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server

There is rumor SharePoint 2019 is the last version of SharePoint. Is it true by any means.

All the search on the internet redirects to Feature of SP 2019. But no links stating about Microsoft plans for SharePoint ahead.

Any links, notes will be helpful.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Their is no announcement from Microsoft that SharePoint 2019 will be the last version of SharePoint onprem. from this i assume Microsoft will bring new version unless they announce otherwise.

For me, it is hard to discontinue the on-prem version as late last year SharePoint survey told us still 50% industry using the SharePoint On-Prem.

Comment: Agreed.  There are many valid use cases for on-prem deployments.  The codebase for both on-prem and Online also appears to be converging - not diverging; if near-parity in PowerShell cmdlets and first-release functionality near-parity (as in sp 2019) is any indication.  **But, then again, I’m no MS MVP.**